# Entries field templating only when entry is added

Tags: craft3

I have a section type **Structure** called How to videos, in which I have field type **Entries**.

Now, when I select "Products" in the field type 'Entries'. I only want the selected Entries Products to show text "Click here to view". If there is no entry added in entries fields it should not show text "Click here to view".

How can I template the Entries field?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do something like this. `entry` is a How to videos entry.

```
{% set relatedProducts = entry.productsEntryField.all() %}

{% if relatedProducts|length %}
    {% for product in relatedProducts %}
        <a href="{{ product.url }}">Click here to view</a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

The [Craft docs on Entries Fields](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries-fields.html#templating) has more info.